# subfig - Problems with reference to table inside figure environment

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, subfloats

I have two figures and one table which I want to be "grouped" together like this:

[image]

This is almost perfectly what I want, but there are 2 problems:

1. As we can see, the title gives the correct index of the figure, but for the table, it gives me its index-1 and I have no idea why...
2. When I try to reference the table, I don't get its number, instead I get the index of the whole figure and the "inner index" (the letter "c").

Do you know, how should I correct these mistakes?

---

#### My code (MWE) - [LINK](https://www.overleaf.com/6925755pfdqxcjptrjf#/23677482/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2  \&  \tablename~\thetable}

\begin{document}
%\addtocounter{table}{1}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{actionK-HTFETI-cv1.png}
}\\
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{actionK-HTFETI-cv2.png}
}
\end{minipage}\hspace{8em}
\subfloat[]{%
\label{tab:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
\textbf{Iter} & \textbf{RMSE} & \textbf{MAPE} \\
\textbf{1} & 0.005235 & 0.141316 \\
\textbf{2} & 0.007103 & 0.138670 \\
\textbf{3} & 0.005464 & 0.220107 \\
\textbf{4} & 0.007080 & 0.184871 \\
\textbf{5} & 0.006369 & 0.220926 \\
\textbf{6} & 0.007130 & 0.234072 \\
\textbf{7} & 0.007505 & 0.222066 \\
\textbf{8} & 0.005203 & 0.179255 \\
\textbf{9} & 0.007091 & 0.277452 \\
\textbf{10} & 0.005718 & 0.165361 \\
\textbf{11} & 0.005801 & 0.160772 \\
\textbf{12} & 0.004936 & 0.154611 \\
\textbf{13} & 0.005661 & 0.142787 \\
\textbf{14} & 0.005435 & 0.102461 \\
\textbf{15} & 0.005426 & 0.091041 \\
\hhline{===}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{mean(RMSE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.006077} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{sd(RMSE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.000874} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{mean(MAPE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.175718} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{sd(MAPE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.051386}
\end{tabular}
}
\captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
\caption{Action of $K$ in HT-FETI - cross-validation}
\label{fig:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}
\end{figure} 

I'm talking about table \ref{tab:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal} and figure \ref{fig:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To get "Table 1" in the caption, use `\addtocounter{table}{1}` before it.

Comment: @samcarter: That would not provide a correct label/cross-referencing then. `\refstepcounter{table}` seems to be better here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you please explain? I get "Figure 1 & Table 1" in the caption and "table 1c and figure 1" in the text. And even after adding hyperref, the linked lead to the correct positions?

Comment: @samcarter: Hm, strange, a `\addtocounter` call should not update the label information, however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table` counter is not automatically incremented by the `figure` environment.

In the table `subfloat` you should specify

`\refstepcounter{table}` in order for it to work. I suggest it to be the first instruction.

I.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2  \&  \tablename~\thetable}

\begin{document}
%\addtocounter{table}{1}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{actionK-HTFETI-cv1.png}
}\\
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{actionK-HTFETI-cv2.png}
}
\end{minipage}\hspace{8em}
\subfloat[]{%
\refstepcounter{table}
\label{tab:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
\textbf{Iter} & \textbf{RMSE} & \textbf{MAPE} \\
\textbf{1} & 0.005235 & 0.141316 \\
\textbf{2} & 0.007103 & 0.138670 \\
\textbf{3} & 0.005464 & 0.220107 \\
\textbf{4} & 0.007080 & 0.184871 \\
\textbf{5} & 0.006369 & 0.220926 \\
\textbf{6} & 0.007130 & 0.234072 \\
\textbf{7} & 0.007505 & 0.222066 \\
\textbf{8} & 0.005203 & 0.179255 \\
\textbf{9} & 0.007091 & 0.277452 \\
\textbf{10} & 0.005718 & 0.165361 \\
\textbf{11} & 0.005801 & 0.160772 \\
\textbf{12} & 0.004936 & 0.154611 \\
\textbf{13} & 0.005661 & 0.142787 \\
\textbf{14} & 0.005435 & 0.102461 \\
\textbf{15} & 0.005426 & 0.091041 \\
\hhline{===}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{mean(RMSE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.006077} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{sd(RMSE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.000874} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{mean(MAPE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.175718} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{sd(MAPE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.051386}
\end{tabular}
}
\captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
\caption{Action of $K$ in HT-FETI - cross-validation}
\label{fig:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}
\end{figure} 

I'm talking about table \ref{tab:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal} and figure \ref{fig:actionK-HTFETI-crossVal}.

\end{document}
```

Producing (with some images of mine) something like:

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer fixed it, thx

Comment: Most impressive... the answering force is strong in you ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer lol…

Comment: This does exactly what I want - thank you very much! See [link](https://www.overleaf.com/6925755pfdqxcjptrjf#/23677482/)